# Smooth Collision (Wall sliding)

Tags: c#, 3d, xna, collision

I recently started learning XNA and C# because of a school project I am doing. I followed this tutorial on YouTube to learn how XNA works with 3D:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XkpZLzT5OV4

It works pretty well actually, and I already made some modification/added some features to my project. I recently started to implement the collision detection, which works well using BoundingBoxes, but the camera literally stops when it collides. I would like it to kinda slide on the wall, as every other first person games do. Basically, the camera stops if the movement is directed to the wall. I would like the camera to "slide" on the wall, removing the movement directed to the wall, and making it only going parallel to the wall. I hope that makes sense. This way, the player will be able to still move around while he's touching the wall.
I looked at a lot of posts on google, and I saw that I needed to play with the player's velocity. However, I don't have any velocity implemented in my code, and I don't know how to add it.

Here are my main classes:

Here is my Camera class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;

namespace Deimos
{
class Camera : GameComponent
{
    // ...

    // Constructor
    public Camera(Game game, Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation, float speed)
        : base(game)
    {
        CameraSpeed = speed;

        // Setup projection matrix
        Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
            MathHelper.PiOver4,
            Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.AspectRatio,
            0.05f,
            1000.0f // Draw distance
        );

        // Set the camera position and rotation
        moveTo(position, rotation);


        PreviousMouseState = Mouse.GetState();
    }





    // Set camera position and rotation
    private void moveTo(Vector3 position, Vector3 rotation)
    {
        // Thanks to the properties set at the beginning, setting up these values will execute 
        // the code inside the property (i.e update our vectors)
        Position = position;
        Rotation = rotation;
    }

    // Update the look at vector
    private void updateLookAt()
    {
        // Build a rotation matrix
        Matrix rotationMatrix = Matrix.CreateRotationX(CameraRotation.X) * Matrix.CreateRotationY(CameraRotation.Y);
        // Build look at offset vector
        Vector3 lookAtOffset = Vector3.Transform(Vector3.UnitZ, rotationMatrix);
        // Update our camera's look at vector
        CameraLookAt = CameraPosition + lookAtOffset;
    }

    // Methods that simulate movement
    private Vector3 previewMove(Vector3 amount)
    {
        // Create a rotate matrix
        Matrix rotate = Matrix.CreateRotationY(CameraRotation.Y);
        // Create a movement vector
        Vector3 movement = new Vector3(amount.X, amount.Y, amount.Z);
        movement = Vector3.Transform(movement, rotate);
        // Return the value of camera position + movement vector

        if (Collision.CheckCollision(CameraPosition + movement)) // Testing for the UPCOMING position
        {
            return CameraPosition;
        }
        else
        {
            return CameraPosition + movement;
        }
    }

    // Method that actually moves the camera
    private void move(Vector3 scale)
    {
        moveTo(previewMove(scale), Rotation);
    }

    // Update method, overriding the original one
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        float dt = (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

        CurrentMouseState = Mouse.GetState();

        // Let's get user inputs
        KeyboardState ks = Keyboard.GetState();

        // Handle basic key movement
        Vector3 moveVector = Vector3.Zero;
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(ForwardKey))
        {
            moveVector.Z = 1;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(BackKey))
        {
            moveVector.Z = -1;
        }

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(LeftKey))
        {
            moveVector.X = 1;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(RightKey))
        {
            moveVector.X = -1;
        }

        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            moveVector.Y = 1;
        }
        if (ks.IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        {
            moveVector.Y = -1;
        }

        if (moveVector != Vector3.Zero) // If we are actually moving (if the vector changed depending on the ifs)
        {
            // Normalize that vector so that we don't move faster diagonally
            moveVector.Normalize();

            // Now we add in move factor and speed
            moveVector *= dt * CameraSpeed;

            DebugScreen.Log(moveVector.ToString());

            // Move camera!
            move(moveVector);
        }


        // Handle mouse movement
        float deltaX;
        float deltaY;
        if (CurrentMouseState != PreviousMouseState)
        {
            // Cache mouse location
            deltaX = CurrentMouseState.X - (Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2); // We devide by 2 because mouse will be in the center
            deltaY = CurrentMouseState.Y - (Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);

            MouseRotationBuffer.X -= MouseSpeed * deltaX * dt;
            MouseRotationBuffer.Y -= MouseSpeed * deltaY * dt;

            // Limit the user so he can't do an unlimited movement with his mouse (like a 7683°)
            if(MouseRotationBuffer.Y < MathHelper.ToRadians(-75.0f))
                MouseRotationBuffer.Y = MouseRotationBuffer.Y - (MouseRotationBuffer.Y - MathHelper.ToRadians(-75.0f));
            if(MouseRotationBuffer.Y > MathHelper.ToRadians(75.0f))
                MouseRotationBuffer.Y = MouseRotationBuffer.Y - (MouseRotationBuffer.Y - MathHelper.ToRadians(75.0f));

            float mouseInverted = (MouseInverted == true) ? 1 : -1;

            Rotation = new Vector3(
                mouseInverted * MathHelper.Clamp(
                    MouseRotationBuffer.Y,
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(-75.0f),
                    MathHelper.ToRadians(75.0f)
                ),
                MathHelper.WrapAngle(MouseRotationBuffer.X), 
                                     // This is so the camera isn't going really fast after some time 
                                     // (as we are increasing the speed with time)
                                     0
                                     );

            // Resetting them
            deltaX = 0;
            deltaY = 0;

        }

        // Putting the cursor in the middle of the screen
        Mouse.SetPosition(Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Width / 2, Game.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.Height / 2);

        PreviousMouseState = CurrentMouseState;

        base.Update(gameTime);

    }
}
}
```

And here is my Collision class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;


namespace Deimos
{
class Collision
{
    // ...
    public Boolean CheckCollision(Vector3 cameraPosition)
    {
        // Creating the sphere of the camera for later collisions checks
        BoundingBox cameraBox = new BoundingBox(
            new Vector3(
                cameraPosition.X - (PlayerDimention.X / 2),
                cameraPosition.Y - (PlayerDimention.Y),
                cameraPosition.Z - (PlayerDimention.Z / 2)
            ),
            new Vector3(
                cameraPosition.X + (PlayerDimention.X / 2),
                cameraPosition.Y,
                cameraPosition.Z + (PlayerDimention.Z / 2)
            )
        );

        // Let's check for collision with our boxes
        if (CollisionBoxesArray != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < CollisionBoxesArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (CollisionBoxesArray[i].Contains(cameraBox) != ContainmentType.Disjoint) // If our player is inside the collision region
                    return true;
            }
        }
        if (CollisionSpheresArray != null)
        {
            // And with our spheres
            for (int i = 0; i < CollisionSpheresArray.Length; i++)
            {
                if (CollisionSpheresArray[i].Contains(cameraBox) != ContainmentType.Disjoint)
                    return true;
            }
        }

        return false;

    }

}
}
```

I really don't know what to do. Thanks a lot.

EDIT: I updated my post removing some unnecessary code so it's more readable for you.
I also explained better my problem.

Comment: Do you mean if you turn the camera around you still stick to the wall? Or the camera just doesn't move if it's facing the wall at all? And do you think you could try to narrow your code down to only what is relative to your question? I think all your code might scare users off (it almost did me).

Comment: Updated it a bit so it's more readable. Basically, the camera here stops if the movement is going in the direction of the wall (meaning that if the next movement is colliding with the wall, the entire camera stops). I would like it to slide. However, if he's not facing the wall it works just fine.

Comment: So do you mean that if the camera isn't directly facing the wall, you want it to slide slightly in the direction it's facing?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I would like! I heard I had to play with velocity, but I have no idea on how to implement it. I thought about calculating the movement vector as well as the vector of the object which is being collided with the camera, but I can't seem to create this last vector

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think something like this might work. This is basically the same thing you did, except the `previewMove` returns a Vector3 that should allow you to slide along the wall. What the function does now is returns a value that checks to see if the camera can move in any of the X, Y, or Z directions of the movement vector, and if the camera can move in the X, Y, and/or Z, it adds that(those) value(s) to the `CameraPosition`.

```
private Vector3 previewMove(Vector3 amount)
{
    // Create a rotate matrix
    Matrix rotate = Matrix.CreateRotationY(CameraRotation.Y);
    // Create a movement vector
    Vector3 movement = new Vector3(amount.X, amount.Y, amount.Z);
    movement = Vector3.Transform(movement, rotate);
    // Return the value of camera position + movement vector

    return CameraPosition + new Vector3(
        Collision.CheckCollision(CameraPosition + new Vector3(movement.X, 0, 0)) ? 0 : movement.X,
        Collision.CheckCollision(CameraPosition + new Vector3(0, movement.Y, 0)) ? 0 : movement.Y,
        Collision.CheckCollision(CameraPosition + new Vector3(0, 0, movement.Z)) ? 0 : movement.Z);

}
```

I haven't tried the code, so I don't know how well this will work. But hopefully it will help.

Comment: This is working perfectly. I tried to do that, but unfortunately I did that in the Update method, with the amount and not the transformed movement vector. With your code, everything is working perfectly. Thanks a bunch!